# How to shutdown Storm Topology cleanly

Tags: shell, apache-storm, topology

Hi i have a storm topology class which sets a spout which listen to kafka queue and two bolts which do processing  over the captured data. Topology class is a main class and can be started on stand alone. I want now to cleanly shutdown this topology with all daemons closed properly from a shell script. I was told that i have to add some code hooks into the code so that it can be closed properly. How to do this? What are the code hooks and how i'm gonna call those from shell script?
Please Help ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a particular method before killing a storm topology](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117845/how-to-call-a-particular-method-before-killing-a-storm-topology)