# how to capture topology kill signal inside storm multilang bolt?

Tags: apache-storm

Is there any way to capture the kill signal at the bolts level, when killing a storm topology using `storm kill myTopology`?

The toplogy is run in cluster mode, and I'm mostly using multilang bolts (node.js and python), and I'd like to run some cleanup routines before shutdown.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117845/how-to-call-a-particular-method-before-killing-a-storm-topology/32118300#32118300

Comment: thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax, I've edited my question to specify for the multilang bolt and therefore not be a dupe of the link you've shared.

Answer (score -1):

With java implementation you just need to override cleanup method in your bolts and close method in spouts. As for multilang bolts, I dont see any equivalent command provided.

Comment: It is not guaranteed by Storm, that `clenup()` will be called... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117845/how-to-call-a-particular-method-before-killing-a-storm-topology/32118300#32118300